# HA Proxy should continue with backup till all sessions are alive when main server up

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I have two servers say MainServer and BackupServer. From this MainServer is main server and BackupServer is my backup sever which I have configured with HA Proxy. Here is my HA configuration

```
 server sso01 MainServer.net check
 server sso01 BackupServer.net check backup
```

Means my all request handle by `MainServer` till this is up and running. When `MainServer` get down, my all logged in users got logged out and next request served by `BackupServer`. Now mean time when `MainServer` got started, I want only new users got handle by `MainServer` and users which are serving by `BackupServer` still continue with `BackupServer` only till they logged in. To identify session, I have added following line in my backend on HA Proxy configuration

```
appsession APP_SESION_ID len 40 timeout 3h request-learn
```

This id we have added in cookie. Because of this my request goes to only that server which was previousaly servered for same. But in this scenario HA proxy work like `roundrobin` algo once `MainServer` up. Hope I make you understand my scenario.

Comment: you need to show the whole relevent section of config otherwise it is really hard to see what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need something like...

```
 balance roundrobin
 cookie SESSIONID prefix indirect nocache
 server sso01 MainServer.net check cookie sso01 
 server sso02 BackupServer.net check cookie sso02 backup
```

(Change SESSIONID to match the name of your session cookie)

In your example your servers both have the same name.